# Trouble with showing posts of a category

Tags: php

```
my `cats` table: id - title
my `posts` table: id - title - content - cat
```

the categories selected when inserting posts is inserted like this:

```
cat1id-cat2id-cat3id
```

for example: 1-2-3 or 2-3-1 or 2-1-3

the not working code:

```
<?php
    $id=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `cat`='{$id}-'");
    $query=mysql_fetch_array($query);
?>
```

how can i show the posts of a category?

Comment: it is dangerous structure of DB. try so `where concat('-', cat, '-') like '-{$id}-'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, [don't use the `mysql_*` set of functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1) -- they are deprecated. Look into [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Second, for your query, you are more suffering from a database architecture issue. IMHO, you should have a `posts` table, a `categories` table, and a `post_categories` table that lets you assign one or more categories to a post. When you do it this way, you have more control.

Finally, to answer your question, when you use the equals operator in your query, it looks for an exact match. To match on a partial piece of text, you most likely need to use the `LIKE` operator like so:

```
$query = "
    SELECT *
    FROM posts
    WHERE
        cat LIKE '$id-%'   OR
        cat LIKE '%-$id-%' OR
        cat LIKE '%-$id'   OR
        cat LIKE '$id'
";
```

That addresses the category being found in the beginning, in the middle, or at the end of the concatenated list (although I cringe looking at it).

But seriously, take a look a refactoring your database structure so you don't even have this problem.

Comment: Have a look at `RLIKE` as well. That allows you to use a regular expression that covers all eventualities without the need for multiple `OR cat LIKE` conditions.

Comment: Good point. Again, none of this would be necessary though with a more conventional relational database structure.

Comment: Yup, agreed, the 2nd table is a MUCH better option.